# Ssh messages do not output to a pipe configured in syslog.conf

Tags: ssh, syslog

I have configured a pipe in syslog.conf for auth.* to capture the ssh syslog error and status messages. I have then a python script that processes this pipe's input and I check that we receive something by writing the content of the pipe to a file.

When running a "ssh root@10.10.10.123" command (IP does not exist on network) I expect to see the ssh error in the file but it's empty.
This used to work but it's not working anymore. What might of happened?

Comment: I would expect that typically only the ssh *daemon* messages get forwarded to syslog, not (error) messages from the ssh *client*.

Comment: Is there a way to generate such a daemon message for testing purposes?

Comment: The [`logger`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command line utility can be used to send messages to a syslog daemon

Answer (score 0):

Check that the syslog.conf is up to date, and if so, replace the python script with the 'tee' utility to see if there is a problem in the syslog